# Why rvalue reference template variable is able to bind to lvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, rvalue-reference

Why rvalue reference template variable `b<int>` is able to bind to lvalue `a`?

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 3;

template<typename T>
T&& b = a;

int main() {
    if(std::is_same_v<decltype(b<int>), int&&>) {
        std::cout << "same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "different\n";
    }
}
```

```
Output: same
```

Comment: Related: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually think this question isn't a duplicate but needs refinement. Yes, `b` is a universal reference here. But it also has a hidden question of why the output was `same`. The answer here is that the correct type that does compile if you want to access the variable is `b<int&>` and not `b<int>`.

Comment: If you `std::cout << b<int> << "\n";` you will get an error, which (I guess/presume) occurs when the template is *instantiated*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why rvalue reference template variable `b<int>` is able to bind to lvalue `a`?

This question makes an incorrect assumption. An rvalue reference `b<int>` is not able to bind to `a`. With your implementation, there is no error because `decltype(b<int>)` itself does not cause the instantiation of `b<int>`.

Whether this is ok or not is a bit unclear. The corresponding quote from the C++17 draft standard is as follows [[temp.inst/6]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#6):

> Unless a variable template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the variable template specialization is **implicitly instantiated when the specialization is used**.

According to this quote, I think that `b` should be instantiated, since `b<int>` is used (even though in an unevaluated context).

However, in the current draft, the wording is different [[temp.inst/7/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#7.sentence-1):

> Unless a variable template specialization is a declared specialization, the variable template specialization is **implicitly instantiated when it is referenced in a context that requires a variable definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program**.

Anyway, once you ensure the instance is required, the you will get a compilation error.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Ws5ajxWYM

Comment: My underlying assumption: "A rvalue reference of non template variable is not able to bind to lvalue". Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @cpp There is no relation to templates. Once a variable template is instantiated, it becomes an ordinary variable/reference.

Comment: yes that is well understood. So that's why I said: My underlying assumption: "A rvalue reference of non template variable is not able to bind to lvalue". And you pointed out that because in my example, the template variable `b<int>` hasn't been instantiated and so it was not an ordinary variable/reference. Therefore, what your were explaining was correct while my assumption did not conflict with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *reference collapsing rules*, "rvalue reference to rvalue reference collapses to rvalue reference, all other combinations form lvalue reference". Although the standard formulates it in other words (C++17 standard draft [[dcl.ref/6]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.ref#6)).

Thus, in case of your variable `b`:

```
T = int    ==> T&& becomes                           int&&
T = int&   ==> T&& becomes int& &&  ==> collapses to int&
T = int&&  ==> T&& becomes int&& && ==> collapses to int&&
```

And back to your code:

```
template<typename T>
T&& b = a;

// On different instantiations this generates:
int&& b<int> = a;    // error, can't bind rvalue reference to lvalue
int& b<int&> = a;    // ok
int&& b<int&&> = a;  // error, can't bind rvalue reference to lvalue
```

From these only `b<int&>` would compile (demonstrating [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MnvKrT3Yn)).

So, why `decltype(b<int>)` happens to pass compilation even though `b<int>` doesn't compile? That's because the `decltype` operator **only checks the declarations are well formed** but doesn't do any instantiation and consequently **doesn't verify the definitions are well formed**. See Daniel's answer for more in-depth explanation based on the C++ standard wording.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the comment. Maybe you are right. I need to think. But in any case, this can be also explained in terms of reference collapsing rules. I'll edit to avoid mention of forwarding references.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you! I thought it through and completely agree with you. Updated the answer.